# maven maven-bundle-plugin - Invalid value for Bundle-Version

Tags: java, maven

Somehow the "default" version regex for maven-bundle-plugin doesn't let me use a
version number like this.

2.0.2021102095

1.1.2021102555

But it accepts these version like this.

2.0.202110201

2.0.20211020101

2.0.202110209999

2.0.2021102099991-SNAPSHOT

This is the error that I'm getting when the version number isn't accepted.
Verifying the given regex the versions should be accepted but somehow it isn't.

Tried several versions of the maven-bundle-plugin but this didn't make any difference.

Anyone understands this one? Is there maybe a way to override the version regex?

Thanks.

```
[ERROR] Bundle xslt.CustomXSLTMediator:CustomXSLTMediator:bundle:2.0.2021102095 : Invalid value for Bundle-Version, 2.0.2021102095 does not match [0-9]{1,9}(\.[0-9]{1,9}(\.[0-9]{1,9}(\.[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)?)?)?
[ERROR] Error(s) found in bundle configuration
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.297 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-22T12:12:05+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:3.5.1:bundle (default-bundle) on project CustomXSLTMediator: Error(s) found in bundle configuration -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:3.5.1:bundle (default-bundle) on project CustomXSLTMediator: Error(s) found in bundle configuration
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
```

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>CustomXSLTMediator</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
            <!--<Bundle-Version>1.0.0.0</Bundle-Version> -->
            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
            <Export-Package>xslt</Export-Package>
            <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: `org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:3.5.1` is from [14-Jun-2018](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.felix/maven-bundle-plugin). What if you try a newer version?

Comment: I tried several versions of the maven-bundle-plugin but unfortunate no luck.

Comment: The regex mentioned in the msg `[0-9]{1,9}(\.[0-9]{1,9}(\.[0-9]{1,9}(\.[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)?)?)?` conforms to the OSGi spec [3.2.5 Version](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/8.0.0/framework.module.html#i2655136). I consider this being a bug in the bundle-plugin.